Is there a way to "flatten" a Tapir schema
I have a generic structure looking something like this:
trait KeyType extends Product

case class DataBag[T <: KeyType](
   key: T
   someData: String, 
   someMoreData: String
)

And a concrete implementation:
   case class NameKey(firstName: String, lastName: String) extends Product
   type PersonData = DataBag[NameKey]

What would be a good/easy/idiomatic way to define a Tapir schema that would "flatten" my structure, and result in json looking like
{
   "firstName": "John",
   "lastName":  "Doe",
   "someData":  "foo",
   "someMoreData": "bar"
}

My goal is to avoid having to define another case class just to produce this output. Is it possible?

I'm not very familiar with Tapir Schema but isn't it something you can achieve in the JSON Encoder you're defining (using your preferred JSON lib)? (I may be missing something obvious, again.. I never had to play with Tapir schemas).

@GaëlJ well, I could define a custom encoder (not that I am sure how to do that either without just enumerating every field in the each object) ... But tapir schema is more than just that: it is also used to generate that openapi spec ... I am hoping to find some way to combine existing implicit schemas (and codecs) for Key, and Data, to just derive the resulting output automatically.

You'll have to define two values. First, a json encoder/decoder, using the json library of your choice (which is used to e.g. encode the response from a high-level type to a string, when running the endpoint's server logic). Second, you'll need a matching tapir Schema, which is used for validation and generating the documentation. (We are developing an experimental uPickle-based pickler module which would combine both derivations in a single run, but it's still not compelte).
But to answer this specific question, you'll need to create some of the schemas manually. It's not the most beautiful code (probably schemas could support these kinds of operations better, bet well :) ).
First, we've got the data types:
trait KeyType extends Product

case class DataBag[T <: KeyType](
    key: T,
    someData: String,
    someMoreData: String
)

case class NameKey(firstName: String, lastName: String) extends KeyType

type PersonData = DataBag[NameKey]

Then, we capture the schemas of all fields of the data bag, except the key, by deriving a schema for an empty key:
case class EmptyKey() extends KeyType
val dataBagWithEmptyKeySchema: Schema[DataBag[EmptyKey]] = {
  implicit val emptyKeySchema: Schema[EmptyKey] = Schema.derived
  Schema.derived
}
val dataBagFieldsWithoutKey: List[SchemaType.SProductField[DataBag[EmptyKey]]] =
  dataBagWithEmptyKeySchema
    .schemaType
    .asInstanceOf[SchemaType.SProduct[DataBag[EmptyKey]]]
    .fields
    .filterNot(_.name.name == "key")

The .asInstanceOf is there because we are sure, that the derived schema is a product one (and not, e.g., a coproduct).
Then, we define a method which takes an arbitrary key, alongside its schema. We need to get the fields of the key, "fix" their .get method so that it properly dereferences the .key, and combine with the data bag fields we captured earlier:
def schemaForDataBag[T <: KeyType: Schema]: Schema[DataBag[T]] = {
  val keyFields: List[SchemaType.SProductField[T]] = 
    implicitly[Schema[T]].schemaType match {
      case SchemaType.SProduct(fields) => fields
      case _                           => throw new IllegalStateException("Key is not a product")
    }

  def fixField(f: SchemaType.SProductField[T]): SchemaType.SProductField[DataBag[T]] =
    SchemaType.SProductField[DataBag[T], f.FieldType](f.name, f.schema, db => f.get(db.key))

  val fixedKeyFields = keyFields.map(fixField)

  val allFields: List[SchemaType.SProductField[DataBag[T]]] = fixedKeyFields ++ 
    dataBagFieldsWithoutKey
      .asInstanceOf[List[SchemaType.SProductField[DataBag[T]]]]

  dataBagWithEmptyKeySchema
    .as[DataBag[T]]
    .copy(schemaType = SchemaType.SProduct(allFields))
}

Finally, we can now use this for any key schema; note that we are using semi-auto derivation, so the implicits need to be defined for each components:
implicit val nameKeySchema: Schema[NameKey] = Schema.derived
implicit val personDataSchema: Schema[PersonData] = schemaForDataBag[NameKey]

println(personDataSchema)

